# C language, file load into 2D array

Tags: c

I am stuck in loading letters from text file into 2D array.

my code is like below;;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, a, b;
    char c;
    char f, filename[100];
    char match[i][j];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < j; b++) {
            match[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < j; b++)
                if ((c != '\n') && (c != '\r'))
                    match[a][b] = c;
        }
    }

    for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < j; b++)
            printf("%c", match[a][b]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and text file contains letters like:
`AAAAA\nBBBBB\nCCCCC\nDDDDD\nEEEEF\n`

I want to load text file to program exactly same, but it is only showing the result
like:
`FFFFF\nFFFFF\nFFFFF\nFFFFF\nFFFFF\n`

can you please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: You read `i` and `j` uninitialized to determine the size of `match`.

Comment: I would expect the code you are showing would give compilation errors. `i`, `j`, and `filename` are all uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

1. `char match[i][j]` this gives compilation error define array with constant
2. `scanf("%d%d%s", &i,&j,&filename);` here instead of &filename write filename because array name is address of array there is no need of `&`
3. when typing file name make sure you type complete address like this   `"c:\\documents\\filename.txt"` note here \ or use can write it as   `"c:/documents/filename.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Ahmed, you never inititalize i, j, and filename in shown code.

Assuming you do it (with your input, I assume i=5, j=5), you first initialize all `match` array to `.` : ok.

Then you read your file character by character and control is it is different from '\n' and `\r`. Let's look what happens at last character of last word, which is a `F`. You loop on full array (a in [0;i[, b in [0; j[), and if character if neither `\r`, nor `\n` (it is not) **you affect it to match[i, j]**

```
for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < j; b++)
        if ((c != '\n') && (c != '\r'))
            match[a][b] = c;
}
```

So at the end of the loop, match only contains `F`, what explains current output ...

You have still another problem, you affect `char c = fgetc(fp)`, and compare it to EOF. That's dangerous, because `fgetc()` and EOF are both declared as `int`.

The `fgetc` loop should be in innermost position to work correctly, only skipping '\n' and `\r` :

```
int c; 
...
for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < j; b++)
        while(((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) && ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r'))) /* skip eol /*
            if (c != EOF) 
                match[a][b] = c;
}
```

This should be enough to fix current errors, but anyway the general program organization is bad. Please write as pseudo code what should happen before coding if you are a beginner. Until the algorithm and structure is good, code will be bad ...